# ASP.net C# repeater loads images and display them vertically before displaying them on Jquery Carousel

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

My repeater will load images vertically covering the webpage before it is displayed with my jQuery carousel plugin. The end result is what I want.

So my question is if there is a way for the repeater to not show the images. So the page will load and display the jQuery with the images in it straightaway.

My images are retrieved from the database, I store them as bytes.

Can someone guide me on how i can hide repeater displaying the images? It makes the website extremely unprofessional...

Sincerely,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="outer" style="width:100%; margin-top:10px;">
        <div style="width:800px; height:700px; margin:0px auto 0px auto;">                
            <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetImages" TypeName="realsolutions.propertyImageDB">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="propertyID" Type="Int32" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:ObjectDataSource>                                     
        <p id="propertyNameP" style="display:inline-block; margin-left:auto">
        <asp:Label ID="lblPropertyLabel" runat="server" Text="PropertyName" Font-Names="Times New Roman" Font-Size="X-Large" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
        </p>
    <script>
                Galleria.loadTheme('js/galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
                Galleria.run('.galleria', {
                    showInfo: true,
                    _toggleInfo: false,
                });
    </script>
    <div class="galleria"   >
      <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%#GetImage(Eval("imageByte")) %>' runat="server" Width="500" Height="300" data-description='<%#Eval("description" )%>'/>             
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
```

So this is how the codes look like for more information. Really could use some help here.